# Binding classes to a div in ember

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I want to bind classes to a div based on a dynamic value in ember; it should hide the DOM element when it is false and add two classes to it when the value is true.

Here is my code:

```
<div {{bindAttr class="App.User.isLoggedIn:alert alert-error:hide" }} >
    ...
</div>
```

However the bindings don't work and it keeps showing the div even when app.User.isLoggedIn is false.

How do you bind multiple classes based on a true condition?

Comment: you'd have to show some more code so we can assist you or you can create a fiddle at jsfiddle.net. Here's a starting template: http://jsfiddle.net/pangratz666/DvdVH/

Comment: for multiple classes u shld try obeservers..will help if u have a fiddle for this..

Comment: Definitely *don't* think that observers are the way to go here (sorry CodeJack). You're referencing `alertError`. Is that a property in your view or something? Post code if you want us to help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So, to get a mix of bound attributes (in your case, class names), you can list separate the binding criteria with spaces.

Basically, in your {{bindAttr ...}} helper, you can write boundAttr="criterion1 criterion2 criterion3", where the individual binding criterion expand out to the following format:

**Property substitution**

```
propertyName
```

This stubs in classNames with two different behaviours:

1. if the property value is a boolean: the dasherized property name
2. if the property value is a string: the string value

**Static class/Always true:**

```
:className
```

Always adds the classname to the div.

**Conditional on an property:**

```
propertyName:trueClass 
propertyName:trueClass:falseClass 
propertyName::falseClass
```

Evaluates the property, and assigns the appropriate class based on truthy/falsy values.

In your case, since you want to have two classes hanging off the same property, you could do:

```
<div {{bindAttr class="App.User.isLoggedIn:alert App.User.isLoggedIn:alert-error:hide"}} >
    ...
</div>
```

Note the spaces here. The first criterion takes care of just the alert class, while the second takes care of the 'alert-error' or 'hide' classes accordingly.

If you wanted something even simpler, you could have a calculated property that determines the string you need to apply in your view or model.

Then you could do

```
// in your view
classesNeeded: function() {

   return App.User.get('isLoggedIn') ? 'alert alert-error' : 'hide';

}.property('App.User.isLoggedIn')
```

And then:

```
<div {{bindAttr class="view.classesNeeded"}} >
        ...
    </div>
```

In the hypothetical case where you needed a third, default class for all cases, you could do:

```
<div {{bindAttr class=":defaultClass view.classesNeeded"}} >
        ...
    </div>
```

You can read up more on attribute and class bindings in the new ember.js doc, here:
http://emberjs.com/guides/templates/binding-element-class-names/

Comment: In your examples, is it really App.User.isLoggedIn:alert:alert-error:hide or just App.User.isLoggedIn:alert-error:hide for the 2nd bound attribute value?

Comment: The second one is just App.User.isLoggedIn:alert-error:hide. Basically you can target one class per true/false in each criterion block. Since I didn't provide a false case in the first criterion, I stuffed it in the second. I think the cleanest solution is to just use the computed property though, to avoid confusion :)

Comment: Dude, thanks for the edit suggestion. I completely overlooked my paste error. I have updated accordingly.

Comment: You should update the last example too as it has the same error. Thanks.

Comment: Done. Same paste error carried down. I'm opting for the property binding case for that example to keep things cleaner. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Try using [classNameBindings](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.View.html) instead. You can add or remove style classes according to the state of properties of your choice

For instance, here's an exmaple from Emberjs documentation:

```
// Applies no class when isEnabled is true and class 'disabled' when isEnabled is false
Ember.View.create({
  classNameBindings: ['isEnabled::disabled']
  isEnabled: true
});
```

Will result in view instances with an HTML representation of:

```
<div id="ember1" class="ember-view"></div>
```

When the isEnabled property on the view is set to false, it will result in view instances with an HTML representation of:

```
<div id="ember1" class="ember-view disabled"></div>
```

Comment: That's good, but it doesn't work on a single div, I don't believe.

Comment: Turn your div into a view for a better control. Remember views are just html elements encapsulated in Ember.View object.

Comment: It really depends on if it's a one-off or not. If it's going to be reused, I definitely agree. But otherwise, an inline helper's probably fine.